# Avoid keyring messages when running command line tools

Tags: ubuntu, python-keyring

I am getting these two messages when running a command line utility (in the case [pgcli](https://www.pgcli.com/)) in an headless Linux running in Docker:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "keyring.backend"
Please enter password for encrypted keyring:
```

How can I configure the logger and the password for keyring, so that I am no longer bothered when running any utility dependent on keyring?

Note that I am on an headless Ubuntu, so I need to know how to do this from the command line.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v1.10.2 is now out, with `keyring` optional. Using `pgcli` on a headless system should not be a problem anymore.

Comment: I have upgraded to v1.10.2. The "No handlers ..." message is gone, but everytime I run `pgcli` it keeps asking me "Please enter password for encrypted keyring:". I do not see there any option to disable the use of keyring in the updated `pgcli`. Please, clarify how can I avoid using keyring. Thanks

Comment: I have configured the `keyring = False` under `[main]` in `~/.config/pgcli/config` but still asks me for the encrypted keyring password. I even deleted `~/.local/share/python_keyring/crypted_pass.cfg` and then when running `pgcli` I get the prompt "Please set a password for you new keyring:".

Comment: Only if I create/edit the file `~/.local/share/python_keyring/keyringrc.cfg` with the entry `[backend] \n default-keyring=keyrings.alt.file.PlaintextKeyring`, then it still uses `keyring` (and `keyring.alt`) but the backend does not require a password, so the previous prompt does not appear. HOWEVER, `pgcli` is still using keyring. Please, check again this situation in `pgcli`, so that the `keyring = False` is really working.

Comment: I'll take a look. Quick question - do you still have `keyring` package installed? You need to uninstall it (`pip uninstall keyring`) so that pgcli won't try to use it.

Comment: Yes, I have installed `keyring (10.1)` and `keyrings.alt (1.3)`.

Comment: Humm ... But uninstalling keyring is not a solution because other applications may require it. The `keyring = False` under `[main]` should be the solution, or an option in the `pgcli` command-line executable to turn off keyring usage.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking into why `keyring = False` does not work. But in the meantime, uninstalling keyring can be a workaround.

Comment: I opened the issue in pgcli to track this: https://github.com/dbcli/pgcli/issues/920. It's better to move the conversation there.

Answer (score 5):

We fixed the problem in v1.10.1, but right now you still need to `pip install keyrings.alt` package for things to work. There's an open PR to handle things better and make `keyring` package optional. As soon as that's merged, we'll do another bugfix release. Stay with us - and thank you for using pgcli!

Comment: How do I install such package? Run `pip install keyring.alt`? I like `pgcli` very much !

Comment: Yes, exactly. But v1.10.2 is now out as well. You should not need `keyring` at all once you install that.

Comment: `pip2 install keyring.alt` and `pip3 install keyring.alt` result in error like `Collecting keyring.alt
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement keyring.alt (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for keyring.alt
`

Comment: There was a spelling mistake above, it's `pip install keyrings.alt` with the extra `s`

Comment: This worked for me on ubuntu, but the password is not encrypted I guess, but I can lice with that